# DataBinding to global ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a WPF application using MVVM pattern, where I have many ObservableCollections. Instead of putting these ObservableCollections into each ViewModel, I placed them into a static class called Observables, which is a member of static class AppCommon. So I can access all observable collections through AppCommon.Observables.AnyObservableINeed.

Now I need to change bindings of UserControl's so they bind to these global ObservableCollection's but I don't know how to refer to these ObservableCollections without changind the DataContext.

I tried adding namespace like

```
xmlns:globals="clr-namespace:Demirbaş.Globals"
```

and then in the ListBox setting the ItemsSource property like

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={globals:Observables.TaşınırSınıfları}}"
```

but that would give me following error:

```
'{globals:Observables.TaşınırSınıfları}' value is not a valid MarkupExtension expression. Cannot resolve 'Observables.TaşınırSınıfları' in namespace 'clr-namespace:Demirbaş.Globals'. 'Observables.TaşınırSınıfları' must be a subclass of MarkupExtension.
```

What is the problem here? Am I using the right XAML syntax to bind to these collections?

**EDIT**
`ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static globals:AppCommon.Observables.TaşınırSınıfları}}"` gives me error :

```
Cannot find the type 'AppCommon.Observables'. Note that type names are case sensitive.
```

I think it cannot refer to nested classes, is it right? What's the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Use [x:Static Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx).

Comment: Can you check my edit please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the namespace of your application but try

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demirbaş"

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding 
    Source={x:Static local:AppCommon+Observables.TaşınırSınıfları}}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [x:Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) markup extension like LPL suggested in a comment to tell WPF it's a static object

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding 
    Source={x:Static globals:Observables.TaşınırSınıfları}}" />
```

Comment: @ArifMertAkçakaya An `x:Static` source has to be in the form of `namespace:ClassName.Property`. You can't have `namespace:ClassName.Property.Property`

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when the namespace reference is not fully qualified and the target binding exists in another assembly.

For example, `xmlns:l="clr-namespace:AssemblyA.Namespace;assembly=AssemblyA".`

If the specific assembly is not specified, the same error message will be displayed "value is not a valid MarkupExtension expression".